# Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I am getting this error:

> Please report: Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501. Some pending callbacks that might have leaked by never being called from native code: {"32461":{"module":"Networking","method":"sendRequest"},"32464":{"module":"Networking","method":"sendRequest"},"32476":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"32500":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"32526":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"32550":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"32574":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"32598":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"32622":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"32646":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"32670":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"32694":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"32718":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"32742":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"32766":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"32790":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"32814":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"32838":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"32862":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"32886":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"32910":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"32934":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"32958":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"32982":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33006":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33030":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33054":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33078":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33102":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33126":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33150":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33174":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33198":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33222":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33246":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33270":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33294":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33318":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33342":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33366":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33390":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33414":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33438":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33462":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33486":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33510":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33534":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33558":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33582":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"33606":{"module":"AsyncLocalStorage","method":"multiGet"},"...(truncated keys)...":451} for this code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react';
import { Alert, FlatList, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation, useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { MultiSelect } from 'react-native-element-dropdown';
import AntDesign from '@expo/vector-icons/AntDesign';
import { CheckBox, Icon } from '@rneui/themed';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import { launchCameraAsync, MediaTypeOptions } from 'expo-image-picker';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/storage';
import { photoFeatureAPI, lastPostTimestampAPI, likesAPI } from '../../api/photoFeature';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { db, auth } from '../../api/fireConfig';
import { addDoc, collection, setDoc, doc, updateDoc, getDoc, onSnapshot, Timestamp, serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions
} from 'react-native';

export default function Forum() {

  const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState(null);
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [hasChangedPicture, setHasChangedPicture] = useState(false);
  const [lastPostTimestamp, setLastPostTimestamp] = useState(null);
  const [canPost, setCanPost] = useState(true);
  const [likedPosts, setLikedPosts] = useState([]);
  const [friendData, setFriendData] = useState([]);
  const [showFriendsPosts, setShowFriendsPosts] = useState(false);
  const [showCamera, setShowCamera] = useState(false);
  const [hasFriendsPostedWithin24Hours, setHasFriendsPostedWithin24Hours] = useState(false);


  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const getData = async () => {
    onSnapshot(doc(db, 'NUS/users', 'profile', auth.currentUser.uid), (doc) => {
      setProfileData(doc.data());
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (profileData) {
      setLikedPosts(profileData.likes || []);
    }
  }, [profileData]);

  const storeLastPostTimestamp = async (timestamp) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('@lastPostTimestamp', timestamp.toString());
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error storing last post timestamp:', error);
    }
  };

  const getLastPostTimestamp = async () => {
    try {
      const timestampString = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@lastPostTimestamp');
      if (timestampString) {
        const timestamp = parseInt(timestampString, 10);
        setLastPostTimestamp(timestamp);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error retrieving last post timestamp:', error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    getLastPostTimestamp();
    setCanPost(isWithin24Hours());
  }, [profileData]);


  const isWithin24Hours = () => {
    if (!lastPostTimestamp) {
      return true;
    }

    const currentTime = Date.now();
    const elapsedTime = currentTime - lastPostTimestamp;
    const hoursPassed = elapsedTime / (1000 * 60 * 60);

    console.log('lastPostTimestamp:', lastPostTimestamp);
    console.log('currentTime:', currentTime);
    console.log('elapsedTime:', elapsedTime);
    console.log('hoursPassed:', hoursPassed);

    return hoursPassed >= 24;
  };

  const takePhoto = async () => {
    let result = await launchCameraAsync({
      mediaTypes: MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.canceled) {
      setImage(result.assets[0].uri);
      setHasChangedPicture(true);
      setFriendData([]); // Clear friendData when taking a new photo


      setShowCamera(false);
    }
  };

  const retakePhoto = () => {
    setImage(null);
    setHasChangedPicture(false);
    setShowCamera(true); // Show the camera again
  };

  const setPhotoFeature = async () => {
  if (hasChangedPicture) {
    if (isWithin24Hours()) {
      photoFeatureAPI(
        { image },
        async () => {
          console.log('uploaded!');

          // Get the current timestamp from Firebase server
          const serverTimestampRef = serverTimestamp();

          // Update the 'lastPostTimestamp' field in the user's profile document
          await updateDoc(doc(db, 'NUS/users', 'profile', auth.currentUser.uid), {
            lastPostTimestamp: serverTimestampRef,
          });

          lastPostTimestampAPI(
            () => {
              likesAPI(
                () => {
                  setShowFriendsPosts(true);
                  setCanPost(false);
                  // Move the lastPostTimestamp update inside the success callback
                },
                (error) => {
                  console.log('Error liking post:', error);
                }
              );
            },
            (error) =>
              Alert.alert(
                'Error',
                error.message || 'Something went wrong, try again later'
              )
          );
        },
        (error) =>
          Alert.alert(
            'Error',
            error.message || 'Something went wrong, try again later'
          )
      );
    } else {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'You can only post a photo once every 24 hours.');
    }
  } else {
    Alert.alert('Warning', 'Please take a photo');
  }
};



  const fetchFriendsPosts = async () => {
    if (profileData && profileData.friend) {
      const formattedFriend = profileData.friend.map(async (uid) => {
        const friendDocRef = doc(db, 'NUS/users', 'Forum', uid);
        const friendDocSnap = await getDoc(friendDocRef);
        const friendData = friendDocSnap.data();

        const friendProfileDocRef = doc(db, 'NUS/users', 'profile', uid);
        const friendProfileDocSnap = await getDoc(friendProfileDocRef);
        const friendProfileData = friendProfileDocSnap.data();

        if (friendData && friendProfileData && friendData.photoFeatureURL) {
          return {
            friendUid: uid,
            photoFeatureURL: friendData.photoFeatureURL,
            name: friendProfileData.name,
            profilePicture: friendProfileData.photoURL,
            lastPostTimestamp: friendData.lastPostTimestamp,
          };
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      });

      Promise.all(formattedFriend).then((formattedData) => {
        const filteredData = formattedData.filter((item) => item !== null);
        setFriendData(filteredData);
        console.log(filteredData);

        const hasPostedWithin24Hours = filteredData.some((item) => isFriendPostWithin24Hours(item));
        setHasFriendsPostedWithin24Hours(hasPostedWithin24Hours);
      });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!canPost) {
      fetchFriendsPosts();
    }
  }, [canPost]);


  const handleLike = async (item) => {
  try {
    const friendUid = item.friendUid;

    const friendDocRef = doc(db, 'NUS/users', 'Forum', friendUid);
    const friendDocSnap = await getDoc(friendDocRef);
    const friendData = friendDocSnap.data();

    let updatedLikes = [];

    if (friendData && friendData.likes) {
      if (friendData.likes.includes(auth.currentUser.uid)) {
        // Unlike the post
        updatedLikes = friendData.likes.filter((id) => id !== auth.currentUser.uid);
      } else {
        // Like the post
        updatedLikes = [...friendData.likes, auth.currentUser.uid];
      }

      // Update the document in Fire store with the updatedLikes array

      await updateDoc(friendDocRef, {
        likes: updatedLikes,
      });

      // Update the likedPosts state with the updatedLikes array
      setLikedPosts(updatedLikes);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error liking post:', error);
  }
};

// Check if the friend's post is also more than 24 hours old
  const isFriendPostWithin24Hours = (item) => {
    if (!item.lastPostTimestamp) {
      return false;
    }

    const currentTime = Date.now();
    const elapsedTime = currentTime - item.lastPostTimestamp.toMillis();
    const hoursPassed = elapsedTime / (1000 * 60 * 60);

    return hoursPassed < 24;
  };



  const renderFriendPost = ({ item }) => {
  const isPostLiked = item.likes && item.likes.includes(auth.currentUser.uid);

  const postTime = item.lastPostTimestamp
    ? item.lastPostTimestamp.toDate().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {
        hour: 'numeric',
        minute: 'numeric',
        hour12: true,
      })
    : '';

  // Skip rendering the friend's post if it's more than 24 hours old
  if (!isFriendPostWithin24Hours()) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.postContainer}>
      <View style={styles.friendInfoContainer}>
        <Image
          style={styles.friendProfilePicture}
          source={{ uri: item.profilePicture }}
        />
        <Text style={styles.friendName}>{item.name}</Text>
      </View>
      <Image style={styles.postImage} source={{ uri: item.photoFeatureURL }} />
      <View style={styles.postButtonsContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={[
            styles.likeButton,
            { backgroundColor: isPostLiked ? '#2de0ff' : 'grey' },
          ]}
          onPress={() => {
            console.log('Like button pressed');
            handleLike(item);
          }}
        >
          <AntDesign name="like1" size={20} color="white" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={[styles.postTime, styles.buttonSpacing]}>{postTime}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

useEffect(() => {
    if (!canPost) {
      fetchFriendsPosts();
    }
  }, [canPost]); // Add the useEffect here


 return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {!canPost ? ( // If canPost is false, show Friend's posts directly
        <View style={styles.friendsPostsContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.friendsPostsText}>Friends' Posts</Text>
          {!hasFriendsPostedWithin24Hours ? (
            <Text style={styles.noPostsText}>Sorry! None of your friends have posted yet.</Text>
          ) : (
            <View style={styles.postsContainer}>
              <FlatList
                data={friendData}
                renderItem={renderFriendPost}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.friendUid}
              />
            </View>
          )}
        </View>
      ) : (
        <>
          {!image && ( // Render the "take photo" section if no image
            <View style={styles.emptyContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.emptyText}>
                You have not taken a photo for today.
                Please take a photo to see your friends' photos.
              </Text>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.selectButton} onPress={takePhoto}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                  {hasChangedPicture ? 'Retake Photo; Open Camera' : 'Open Camera'}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          )}

          {image && ( // Render the "post photo" section if there's an image
            <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
              <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={styles.image} />
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={[styles.uploadButton, !hasChangedPicture && styles.disabledButton]}
                onPress={setPhotoFeature}
                disabled={!hasChangedPicture}
              >
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Post</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          )}
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  selectButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#2de0ff',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  imageContainer: {
    alignItems:'center',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  image: {
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  emptyContainer:{
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
  emptyText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 16,
    color: 'black',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  uploadButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#2de0ff',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  disabledButton: {
    opacity: 0.5,
  },
  spacer: {
    height: 20,
  },
  friendsPostsContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  friendsPostsText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginTop: 50,
  },
  postContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 400,
    height: 450, 
    marginVertical: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#FAF9F6',
  },
  friendInfoContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 10,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
  friendProfilePicture: {
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 20,
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  friendName: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  postImage: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '70%', 
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  postButtonsContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 20,
  },
   postButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#2de0ff',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginHorizontal: 5,
  },
  buttonSpacing: {
    marginLeft: 120,
  },

  likeButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },

  noPostsText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#2de0ff',
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginTop: 250,
  },
});
```

This is for an app I am making for a project. I do not know why I am getting this error.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).